# Chern class of the tensor product of a torsion free sheaf with a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, intersection-theory

I'am try to work with Chern class of the coherent sheaves, in this sense. If I have a vector bundle $E$ of rank $r$ and $L$ a line bundle we have the Chern class property

$$c_{r}(E\otimes L) = \sum_{i = 0}^{r}c_{i}(E)c_{1}(L)^{r-i}.$$

I need a similar result for coherent sheaf.

If I have a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ over a smooth projective variety X we consider a locally free resolution

$$0 \longrightarrow E_{n} \longrightarrow \cdots \longrightarrow E_{0} \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow 0.$$

We can define the total Chern class of $\mathcal{F}$ by

$$c(\mathcal{F}) = \displaystyle\Pi_{i = 0}^{n} c(E_{i})^{(-1)^{i}}.$$

**My question:** Is true that $c_{n}(\mathcal{F}\otimes L) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}c_{i}(\mathcal{F})c_{1}(L)^{n-i},$ for the coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$? If is not there exist the similar relationship?

Thank you !!

Comment: If $L$ is a line bundle, you have an exact sequence by tensoring the resolution by $L$ and then you get $c(\mathcal{F}\otimes L)=\sum c(E_i\otimes L)^{(-1)^i}$. Now using the formula for vector bundles (which are the only ones appearing on the right), what does algebra give you?

Comment: Mohan, thank you for your answer! But i am a mistake in Chern Class definition. It is necessary to exchange the sum for a production.